# speed performance: $in vs $lookup with indexed field, _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Assumption:

- All data and indexes are in RAM.

First query:

```
{
  $in: [user_id, array_of_user_ids_with_length_1000]
}
```

Second query:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "col_b",
    localField: "_id", 
    foreignField: "user_id",
    as: "joined_field"
  }
}

where col_b has 10B documents and is indexed, uniquely, on "user_id".
```

My reasoning:

The second query should be faster because the `$in` operation in the first query will have worst case time complexity of O(1000), while the worst case time complexity of the second query is O(log(10B)) = O(23).

Is my reason correct? Will the second query indeed be faster than the first? If not, what did I get wrong? What about in practice, can we expect this to be case in real data, hardware, RAM, use case, etc.?

Comment: What is the explain plan? Did you try and compare?

Comment: This question appears answerable at the first principle level. Unless there is something that I didn't understand

Comment: I don't think so. Try it, and when one solution is as fast as the other one then you don't need to care about it.

Comment: The time complexity of the second query is O(log(10B)) to find a single document.

Comment: Finding a single document serves the same purpose as the `$in` query. But the `$in` is O(1000). We are assuming that only few documents exist and there will be a `{$limit: 1}` stage.

Answer (score -1):

`$lookup` for joining data from other collections, and `$in` for finding similar data groups in a single collection, it all depends on you're use case.